# Is there BlackoutDates or something similar for DatePicker in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

In WinForms and WPF, we can use BlackoutDates to block certain dates in the DatePicker. I can see that there is nothing similar in .NET MAUI. Is there any solution for this?

I have searched for something similar in .NET MAUI and I cannot find anything.

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Maui maps each control to a corresponding native control on each platform. Research how dates are picked on each platform you care about. If a platform has that feature, then it should be possible to write a custom handler for DatePicker, that does what you want on that platform. You might also want to look into third-party controls.

Comment: I would count "blackout" days more like business logic. It's very rare thing to prevent days from selection. So better to make validation in code (and show calendar again), than overloading calendar w rare functions. Just IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason and ToolmakerSteve said that, there is nothing like BlackoutDates in MAUI. For MAUI, only these two properties: `MinimumDate` `MaximumDate`

```xml
<DatePicker MinimumDate="2023-06-01" MaximumDate="2023-06-09"/>
```

And this is [the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHJFV.png).

**Update:**

According to salman_sali, creating a custom date picker component is a way to blackout certain individual dates and certain DaysOfWeek for MAUI.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to blackout certain individual dates and certain DaysOfWeek. I ended up creating a custom date picker component.

Comment: @salman_sali Nice!  I update the wiki answer according to your comment.